# Print only one data among same value collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

How i print only one value among same value collection form my mongodb collection.

eg: my mongodb collection

```
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "city": "ny"
},
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "city": "LA",
}
```

when i print name then only one "xyz" need to be appear.I am using nodejs and mongodb.

Thanks

Comment: How do you print? Javascript on a website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you're prob looking for it to find only distinct values, there is a mongoose (the node mongo db interface library) query for that:

```
CityNameModel.find().distinct('name', function(error, names) {
    // names is an array of all unique city names
});
```